# Datagridview can't get the text from selected row specific control button field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following aspx:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12px" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowHeader="False"                     
                GridLines="None" EnableModelValidation="True" Width="22%" >
                    <RowStyle BorderStyle="None"  Height="40px" HorizontalAlign="Left"/>                            
                        <Columns>                                           
                            <asp:HyperLinkField Text="&lt;img src='../Images/CMM/download.png'/&gt;"></asp:HyperLinkField>                                                                
                            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" DataTextField="codigo" DataTextFormatString="{0:d}"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ControlStyle-Font-Underline="true">
                                <ControlStyle Font-Underline="True" />
                            </asp:ButtonField>
                        </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                 </asp:GridView>
```

and I have the following apsx.cs file code:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                  
        CallSaveAs(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);   
}
```

the GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text is empty but i can see it on the Debug

i have also tried:

```
ButtonField bf = (ButtonField)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Controls[0];
```

but i get Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField'

**Finally found the solution:**

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs)
    {        
        LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Controls[0];              
        CallSaveAs(lb.Text);   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ButtonField renders as multiple controls and the one you want is a LinkButton so what you need to do is reference the second control and cast it to LinkButton like this -

```
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Controls[1];
string text = btn.Text;
```

Comment: Metodo GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged - Exception :: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at NovoPedidoWeb.GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) -

Comment: Interesting, have you tried keeping it as Controls[0] but casting it to a LinkButton?

Comment: that is waht i am trying now but i take a lot time to deploy

Comment: thanks very much i would vote up but i need to have 15 points

Answer (score 0):

ButtonField bf = (ButtonField)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Controls[0];

Now try....

Same condition with different data source worked here....

Comment: instead of controls[0] , use .Text or any string container

Comment: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField'